# Change Top property of control at run time

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to change top position of a label at run time . 
Suppose `Top = 500` is already but i want `Top = 600`
when i execute `Top = 600` it will be executed but still value in `Top` is `500`

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Show the code you have used to do this

Comment: WinForm/WebForm ? Where is the code man???

Comment: Code is required here to provide answer

Comment: obvOMSCaption.Top=32718                                                                                 picPage.Controls.Add(obvOMSCaption)        after this statement top become 32586

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming win forms here.

Setting the top property will cause the control to move to the new top and adjust it's top property accordingly unless the control is docked. In that case the docking property takes precedence and the top property will remain as it was.